# Render large data on IE8 using primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, internet-explorer-8

In my webpage, there is an editable datatable which contains about 100 rows with 30 columns each. I am using JSF as my framework with primefaces datatable. In latest browser it works but for IE8 on low-end machine (P4 2GB RAM), it is extremely slow. Can you please suggest some approach so that page gets loaded quickly.

Some constraints (Really silly constraints but I am helpless:(

1. I can not upgrade my machine
2. I can not upgrade my browser or use some other browser
3. I can not use pagination or live scroll

Comment: I am afraid that with a P4 processor that everything will be slow. :(

Comment: Tell your boss / stakeholder that he/she is the constraint

Comment: yes.. its true.. p4 is a problem , but in mozilla it is not that slow. IE8 is pathetic

Comment: If you absolutly have to show the table in one go that means you are stuck... you can't use lazy loading to cut up the data in pieces.

Comment: yes i am stuck. but there must be some work around.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use pagination on the database. It could be transparent to the final user and maybe improve your application performance.

Comment: Thxx but as per requirement , i need to load data at one go. pagination is not an option for me